# Lucene / Solr: query for matching all restrictions or only a subset

Tags: java, solr, lucene

I would like to have a multiple restrictions query in Lucene, which does not only return documents that match all restrictions(as first results), but also include ones that only match a subset of restrictions (worse matches at the end of the result list).

So say I have the following restrictions coming from the user:

```
A:"a" AND B:"b" AND C:"c"
```

Technically, I could execute the following queries **one by one**:

- `A:"a" AND B:"b" AND C:"c"`
- `A:"a" AND B:"b"`
- `B:"b" AND C:"c"`
- `A:"a" AND C:"c"`
- `A:"a"`
- `B:"b"`
- `C:"c"`

then aggregate (and based on how specific the query was, order) the results programmatically, but that seems to be a terrible approach.

So is there any way to tell Lucene, *"please fetch the documents, that match the full criteria, but please also fetch ones that only match a subset of my criteria"*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's exactly what the `OR` operator is for. It does not return the resulting documents randomly, but by score (unless you specify another value as `sort` parameter).

The so called *Coordination Factor* (or `coord-factor(q,d)` in the formulas) will penalize documents for which not all searched fields matched, e.g. by factor 0.8 if only 4 of 5 fields match. See 
https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_6_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/TFIDFSimilarity.html